# POST "/@%7B/login%7D", parameters={masked}

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I hit the login form after entering credentials, it shows

> White label Error Page.
> This application has no explicit mapping for `/error`, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Thu Mar 05 20:30:41 NPT 2020
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> No message available

After entering URL `/login` it becomes `http://localhost:8080/@%7B/login%7D` automatically.

Here is my **controller code**:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password, ModelMap modelMap) {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        return "findFlight";
    } else {

        modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "nvalid username or password .please tryagain");

    }
    return "login/login";
}
```

here is `login.html` file

```html
<form action="@{/login}" method="post" >
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img th:src="@{/imgs/img_avatar2.png}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <label for="email"><b>email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="email" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**my console is**

```
2020-03-05 20:58:13.147  INFO 5304 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-05 20:58:13.147  INFO 5304 --- [           main] c.r.f.FlightreservationApplication       : Started FlightreservationApplication in 2.841 seconds (JVM running for 3.45)
2020-03-05 20:58:17.359  INFO 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-05 20:58:17.359  INFO 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-05 20:58:17.359 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2020-03-05 20:58:17.363 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2020-03-05 20:58:17.363  INFO 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
2020-03-05 20:58:17.368 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/@%7B/login%7D", parameters={masked}
2020-03-05 20:58:17.373 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/templates/", "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-03-05 20:58:17.378 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-03-05 20:58:17.379 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2020-03-05 20:58:17.382 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2020-03-05 20:58:17.383 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2020-03-05 20:58:17.398 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2020-03-05 20:58:17.400 DEBUG 5304 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: i hae added my console please have alook

Comment: What templating language are you using for your HTML (are you even using a templating library to process it?), because it looks like `<form action="@{/login}" ..` ended up verbatim in the HTML output, so if you submit the form, it tries to post to the URL `/@%7B/login%7D` (%7B is `{` and %7D is `}`)

Answer (score 0):

Helow

Change the line:

```
<form action="@{/login}" method="post" >
```

to:

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" >
```

Best regards

Comment: Change the line:      <form action="@{/login}" method="post" >
to:                            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" >

Comment: Note the  "th:" before "action".